# Linux SMB Server + PAM: How to give LDAP users permissions?

Tags: linux, ldap, server-message-block

I have a Linux Mint SMB server set up the default way (i.e. the way it comes from `apt-get`), so I have this set:

```
passdb backend = tdbsam
```

I have LDAP correctly configured with PAM (and user logins via ssh work correctly).

I tried to do this in the settings of a share:

```
valid users = family
```

Where `family` is a group on the LDAP server.

However, when I try to connect to the server as an ldap user, it doesn't let me connect. If I connect as a local user, it works.

Furthermore, the Ubuntu "Shared Folders" control panel does not show any network users in the list of people to grant access to various shares.

So: **why isn't this working?**

Additions:

Here is what I believe to be a relevant portion of the [very] long log file tagged by name of the computer that's connecting:

> Mapping user [SEC1][christopher] from workstation [DEFIANT]
>
> attempting to make a user_info for christopher (christopher)
>
> making strings for christopher's user_info struct
>
> making blobs for christopher's user_info struct
>
> made a user_info for christopher (christopher)
>
> check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user
>   [SEC1][christopher]@[DEFIANT] with the new password interface
>
> check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [SEC1][christopher]@[DEFIANT]
>
> check_ntlm_password: auth_context challenge created by random
>
> challenge is:
>
> [0000] F9 89 7B 47 67 0B 29 49                            ..{Gg.)I
>
> Check auth for: [christopher]
>
> check_ntlm_password: guest had nothing to say
>
> Check auth for: [christopher]
>
> is_myname("SEC1") returns 1
>
> push_sec_ctx(0, 0) : sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
>
> push_conn_ctx(0) : conn_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
>
> setting sec ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 1
>
> Security token: (NULL)
>
> UNIX token of user 0 Primary group is 0 and contains 0 supplementary
>   groups
>
> pdb_getsampwnam (TDB): error fetching database.  Key: USER_christopher
>
> pop_sec_ctx (0, 0) - sec_ctx_stack_ndx = 0
>
> check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'christopher' in passdb.
>
> check_ntlm_password: sam authentication for user [christopher] FAILED
>   with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
>
> check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [christopher] ->
>   [christopher] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
>
> Checking NTLMSSP password for SEC1\christopher failed:
>   NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
>
> No such user christopher [SEC1] - using guest account

Note that "SEC1" is the name of the server and "DEFIANT" is the name of the client. I also tried connecting with the username "\"; it correctly recognized the domain but that still didn't change anything.

Comment: The right syntax for adding a group in `valid users` parameter is `+family`. However, this doesn't seem to solve the problem, because connection as a local user works. Could you set `log level = 10` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and check log files with `tail -F /var/log/samba/*`?

Comment: Also, does `pdbedit -L` list all users defined in your LDAP server?

Comment: @AndersonM.Gomes `pdbedit -L` lists the local user but not any of the network users. Also, I'm looking at the log file to try to pair it down because from the time my computer sent my password to the time the log ended, 1306 lines came out.

Comment: @AndersonM.Gomes See the updates

Answer (score 2):

While PAM authenticates users against the LDAP database, Samba authenticates users against its `tdbsam` backend. The simple solution is adding them with either `smbpasswd -a <username>` or `pdbedit -a -u <username>`. The complicated solution is using LDAP as Samba's `passdb backend`.

**EDIT**: note that if you configure Samba to use LDAP as `passdb backend`, it will authenticate LDAP users only, not local ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, requiring users to enter a password specifically for samba via command line isn't a viable option. Also, the directory server is OS X Server's OpenDirectory and, from what I've read, it has issues when using it as the backend to samba directly via the LDAP back-end (which I've tried to do...)